# Cannot get recordId on Aura controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, component, get

```
create: function (cmp) {
        
        var name = cmp.find("name").get('v.value');
        var stat = cmp.find("stat").get('v.value');
        var comment = cmp.find("comment").get('v.value');
        var action = cmp.get("c.getDoc");
        action.setParams({
            
            recordId: component.get("v.recordId"), 
            name: name,
            stat: stat,
            comment: comment

        });
        console.log('ENTER ON CREATE ->' + action);
        
    },
```

Code is stuck on **recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),** , why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your function definition, the component parameter name is `cmp` and not `component` so you need to do `cmp.get("v.recordId"),`.
Also, you will need to enqueue action like this `$A.enqueueAction(action);` to initiate the server call. Check the docs :[Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

Comment: Thanks! It is solved